# Programmable Bluetooth LE device to Simulate a HW

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am writing a mobile application which interacts with a Bluetooth LE hardware. As a starting point, I would like to have a dummy Bluetooth LE device which can be programmed to simulate the HW. What are the Bluetooth LE devices available in market which can are programmable ?

I tried a little bit of googling and could not find a proper answer. Below are a few options which I found.

V.BTTN

PSoC

Not sure, whether they are the right ones or not..!!!

Can anyone please help with some options for achieving the same ?

Comment: The simplest solution is probably to write an app that simulates your hardware on another ios or Android device

Comment: Bluez has the ability to run a GATT server but I'm not familiar with it so I can't help with the specifics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arduino-based products are probably your cheapest option. I use [Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2479) myself. It is very cheap and you don't have to look far for a huge online database of examples and tutorials.